# Evaluating noexcept specifier before template type deduction

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, noexcept

Please see the following code:

```
#include <utility>

struct A {
  A(int, int) {}
};

struct tag {};

template <class... Args>
struct is_noexcept {
  static constexpr bool value = noexcept(A{std::declval<Args>()...});
};

struct B : A {
  //#1
  template <class... Args>
  B(tag, Args&&... args) noexcept(/*Here*/is_noexcept<Args...>::value) :
    A{std::forward<Args>(args)...} {}

  //#2
  B(int x, int y) : A{x, y} {}
};

int main()
{
  B x{0, 0};
}
```

This code seems to be accepted by GCC/Clang, but MSVC 2017 rejects it.
It seems that MSVC compiler tries to compute the noexcept specifier before understanding that #1 is not an appropriate overload (due to incompatibility between `tag` and `int`) so should be discarded. Thus it tries to evaluate `is_noexcept<int>::value` and finds out `noexcept(A{std::declval<int>()})` is ill-formed. Since this happens not in the immediate context , this is not where SFINAE comes in, so hard error.

(In fact, I'm not pretty sure about this, but I've confirmed that if I put `noexcept(A{std::declval<Args>()...})` instead of `is_noexcept<Args...>::value` at `/*Here*/` to make the failure inside the immediate context, the MSVC compiler happily drops #1 and calls #2. Is this right?)

I suspect GCC/Clang is right and MSVC is wrong, but which one is correct?

Comment: I would say "As usual".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an MSVC bug. The rule, as a result of [CWG 1330](https://wg21.link/cwg1330), in [[except.spec]/13](http://eel.is/c++draft/except.spec#13) is:

> An exception specification is considered to be *needed* when:
>
> - in an expression, the function is the unique lookup result or the selected member of a set of overloaded functions ([basic.lookup], [over.match], [over.over]);
> - the function is odr-used or, if it appears in an unevaluated operand, would be odr-used if the expression were potentially-evaluated;
> - the exception specification is compared to that of another declaration (e.g., an explicit specialization or an overriding virtual function);
> - the function is defined; or
> - the exception specification is needed for a defaulted special member function that calls the function. *[ Note:* A defaulted declaration does not require the exception specification of a base member function to be evaluated until the implicit exception specification of the derived function is needed, but an explicit noexcept-specifier needs the implicit exception specification to compare against. *— end note ]*
>
> The exception specification of a defaulted special member function is evaluated as described above only when needed; similarly, the *noexcept-specifier* of a specialization of a function template or member function of a class template is instantiated only when needed.

The exception specification of `B(tag, Args&&...)` is not needed (we don't satisfy any of those bullets), so it should not be instantiated.

Note also that substitution failure in the exception specification is **not** part of the immediate context, and would not be a SFINAE-friendly error.

Comment: Thanks! The first bullet together with the final sentence seem to say that noexcept specifier is evaluated when ````B(tag, Arg&&...)```` is actually chosen to be called. Right? And I'm a bit confused of the fourth bullet. What it mean by "defined" for function templates or member functions of class templates? Or is the fourth bullet applied only to non-template functions?

Comment: @JunekeyJeon Templates are defined when they're instantiated.

Comment: Thanks. And, though I would agree that utilizing SFINAE using noexcept specification would be a not so good idea in general even if that were possible, could you explain why noexcept is not part of the immediate context? If my understanding is correct, starting from C++17, noexcept is now a part of function type, and any "Ill-formed expression used in the function type" can cause SFINAE. Isn't it?

Comment: @JunekeyJeon It's not because the rules say it's not - you only evaluate the exception specifier after you've already picked the function. We're already done with overload resolution at that point, too late to back up.

Comment: Ah, indeed! Thanks :)